# Is a to be verb "are" has ommited from the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

As I was reading a book about **Programming Languages**, I saw a part that I thought the term "are" has been omitted from the sentence.
Here is the whole text:

> **Our API**
>
> The API we are going to develop is a simple but useful one (well
> useful for me anyway!).  With my ever-advancing years and worsening
> state of decrepitude, I wanted to write  an API that would store
> “command-line snippets,” (e.g., dotnet new web -n ), as
> I’m finding it harder and harder to recall them when needed. In
> essence it’ll  become a command-line repository that you can query
> should the need arise. Each “resource” will have the following
> attributes: • Howto: Description of what the prompt will do, for
> example, add a  firewall exception, run unit tests, etc. • Platform:
> Application or platform domain, for example, Ubuntu  Linux, Dot Net
> Core, etc. • Commandline: The actual command line snippet, for
> example, dotnet  build.
>
> Our API will follow the standard set of create, read, update, and
> delete (CRUD)  **operations common** to most REST APIs, as described in
> the following table below.

I think that there was an "are" between the two bold terms "operations" and "common".
Actually I described the whole last 3 lines as:

> Our API will follow the standard set of create, read, update, and
> delete (CRUD)  operations **are** common to most REST APIs, as described in
> the following table below.

And as you can see above, I added "are" between "operations" and "common".
Now, did I add it correctly? If I don't, then how to translate last 3 lines??

Comment: Prime Mover's answer is correct, but I will just point that you can't just add *are* because that looks like a second main verb.  It's easier to see if you simplify the sentence: Our API **will follow** (the main verb) ...the set of operations *are* (?!) common...

Answer (score 3):

I believe it should be parsed as:

> Our API will follow the standard set of create, read, update, and delete (CRUD) operations **which are** common to most REST APIs, as described in the following table below.

The thrust of this sentence is to mean:

- Some operations are common to most REST APIs and some are not. (Some REST APIs may implement some more sophisticated and / or technically complex operations.) Be assured that our API will implement (at least) those common ones which every API needs to implement.

Comment: So adding "that are common to ..." is correct too? Isn't that?

Comment: @HosseinDara Either will do, I believe. I have never got my head round the difference between "that" and "which" in this context. There may be differences between American English and British English, for that matter. It is probable that nobody cares.